# Brocade VDX 6740 VLANs and dual-mode

Tags: vlan, brocade

We have a VDX 6740 that serves as a switch for our SAN for our vSphere environment. We've introduced a new SAN that we'd like only one host to have access to.

As I have it setup now:

```
VLAN 2 for SAN 1 and vSphere traffic
192.168.2.1/28
ports 1/0/1-6

VLAN 3 for new SAN and vSphere traffic from one ESXi host
192.168.3.1/28
ports 1/0/7-12
```

How can I allow ports 1/0/11 and 1/0/12 talk to both VLAN 2 and 3? The ESXi host on these ports will need to be able to talk to the new SAN for file storage as well as the old for vSphere traffic.

I can't seem to figure out on the VDX 6740 how to enable `dual-mode` as we typically do on other Brocade switches in our environment. From the documentation it looks as though it only supports tagged or untagged traffic, not both, and currently I have all ports untagged with:

```
switchport
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
```